# Show content of tables in some textboxes

Tags: c#, sql-server

I wrote this code to show content of tables in SQL Server in a form in c# and those are displayed in a datagridview! If I want to show them in some textbox, what should I do?

```
 SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=127.0.0.1;Initial Catalog=jadid;Integrated Security=True");
 SqlCommand com_sel = new SqlCommand();

 DataSet ds = new DataSet();
 SqlDataAdapter adap = new SqlDataAdapter(com_sel);
 com_sel.CommandText = "select * from t2 where same'" + textBox1.Text + "' ";
 com_sel.CommandType = CommandType.text;
 com_sel.Connection = con;
 //com_sel.Parameters.Add("@p1", textBox1.Text);
 con.Open();
 ds.Clear();
 adap.Fill(ds);
 com_sel.ExecuteNonQuery();
 dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

for (i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1; i++) { textBox1.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Column"].ToString();

Comment: A textbox can show **one value** - one column in one row. How do you want to show your data then?? If you get back 50 rows - which one gets displayed?

Comment: I mean in diffrent textboxes

Comment: one row in diffrent textboxes

Comment: I read the question three times and still could not figure out what you are trying to achieve. Perhaps you may consider rewriting it or clarify further with an example.

Comment: yes,you're right,I WANNA rewrite them

Comment: i wanna show content of one row in some textboxes to rewrite them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this code:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=127.0.0.1;Initial 
Catalog=jadid;Integrated Security=True"); 

SqlCommand com_sel = new SqlCommand(); 

DataSet ds = new DataSet();   
SqlDataAdapter adap = new

SqlDataAdapter(com_sel);  

com_sel.CommandText = "select * from t2 where id=1";  //

com_sel.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
com_sel.Connection = con; 
com_sel.Parameters.Add("@p1",textBox1.Text);
con.Open();
ds.Clear();
adap.Fill(ds); 
com_sel.ExecuteNonQuery();  

dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];

int i; //this way you display the data in the textbox 
//TextBox1 is your textbox name 
//lessthen:- less than sign not write

for(i=0;i lessthen ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count-1;i++) {

TextBox1.Text=ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Column"].ToString(); 
}
```

Comment: does it work when I haven't any store procedure in sql server?

Comment: yes com_sel.CommandType = CommandType.Text and remove this com_sel.Parameters.Add("@p1",textBox1.Text);

Comment: sorry,for(i=0;i<ds.Tables[0].Roes.count-1){

Comment: sorry,but is it correct?

Comment: please check it again:-(

Comment: i think you may miss something in FOR

Comment: what type of error you retrive

Comment: try this   for(i=0;i<ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count-1;i++) {
 
  TextBox1.Text=ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Column"].ToString(); }

Comment: could you please tell me which line is wrong that it says this error:Must declare the scalar variable "@p1";  in adap.Fill(ds);

Comment: you can add for loop after the your code..

Comment: could you please tell me what shoud i write instead of this line?com_sel.CommandText = "select * from t2 where same=@p1";

Comment: first you have write your code that has been working

Comment: after you have paste my code for(i=0;i<ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count-1;i++) { TextBox1.Text=ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Column"].ToString(); }

Comment: it dosen't show anything in textboxes:-(

Comment: pls give me your code and check data is exits or not

Comment: it shows the content of tabels in datagrid view but no in textboxes!is it rigth?textBox1.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Column"].ToString();then textbox1 shoun't be change?

Comment: give me your code textbox1 is a your textbox name

Comment: i change the code in my question,please read the code!now my question is that where the information will be show?all of them in textbox1???

Comment: "select * from t2 where same'" + textBox1.Text + "' "; rewrite to  "select * from t2 where same='" + textBox1.Text + "' ";

Comment: for (i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1; i++) { textBox1.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Column"].ToString(); } rewrite to for (i = 0; i <= ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1; i++) { textBox1.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Column"].ToString(); }

Comment: thanks,but my question is that where are the other information!i wanna show name in textbox1 and family in textbox2?

Comment: you have 3 column then design 3 textbox and fill the data like that for (i = 0; i <= ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1; i++) {       textBox1.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Column1"].ToString(); textBox2.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Column2"].ToString(); textBox3.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Column3"].ToString(); }

Comment: that is my last question,I promise:-(